# Не видит TAG в xml

Tags: android, xml

Ругается на этот код. Что я делаю не так?

code:

```
 Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Chat");
                if(!fragment.isVisible()){
                    //Log.i(TAG,dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    push(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }
```

xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Chat.Chat"
    android:tag="Chat">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/chat_input_mess"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chat_send"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/chat_send" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/chat_send"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chat_send"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/chat_list"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="6dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chat_input_mess" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: by.ittech.test_chat, PID: 22231
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isVisible()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: @pavlofff ok,а можно сделать что-то подобное с tag view?

Comment: (fragment == null || !fragment.isVisible()) - это условие говорит о том, что если фрагмент == нул (не добавляли на экран или убит GC) ИЛИ фрагмент не виден, то условие "пользователь не видит этот фрагмент" верно. То есть продолжайте программно добавлять таг, ведь если его вы ранее не добавляли на экран то пользователь не может его видеть.

Comment: @Chaynik помогло!Вам плюсик)

Answer (score 2):

tag `View` и tag фрагмента - разные вещи. Фрагмент не будет найден по тегу, назначенному для какого то `View`, ему нужно присваивать собственный тэг через метод `FragmentManager`, например:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, TAG);
```

При выводе фрагмента на экран присваивайте ему тэг, как в методе выше. А проверку на видимость делайте после проверки на `NULL`:

```
if(fragment!=null && !fragment.isVisible()){
                //Log.i(TAG,dataSnapshot.getKey());
                push(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }
```

Comment: найти фрагмент по тэгу его View? - нет

Comment: ok,я знал про этот метод объявления,но есть один минус: пока не зайдёшь в фрагмент, который мне нужно,TAG не присваивается. А мне нужно,чтобы человек, который к примеру не видит данный фрагмент, мог получать уведомления. Но я этого не могу сделать,ибо чтобы это работало,нужно зайти в фрагмент,чтобы активировался его tag. При запуске моего приложения открывается иной фрагмент

Comment: как изначально добавить TAG франменту,не запуская его?

Comment: программно никак

Comment: Ну а разве не логично, что если человек на него не зашел (неоткрывал) то он его не видит? (fragment == null || !fragment.isVisible()) - это условие говорит о том, что если фрагмент == нул (не добавляли на экран или убит GC) ИЛИ фрагмент не виден, то условие верно.

Comment: @Chaynik Да, верно, с корректностью прохождения условия не было времени разбираться, к сожалению :(